# import jfram lib for jyz3d example in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jframe

Hi i have sample code for using jyz3d in android , using IDE eclipse.

```
import org.jzy3d.chart.Chart;
import org.jzy3d.colors.Color;
import org.jzy3d.colors.ColorMapper;
import org.jzy3d.colors.colormaps.ColorMapRainbow;
import org.jzy3d.maths.Range;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Builder;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Mapper;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.concrete.OrthonormalGrid;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Shape;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Chart chart = getChart();

    frame.add((javax.swing.JComponent) chart.getCanvas());

    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("test");
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static Chart getChart() {
    // Define a function to plot
    Mapper mapper = new Mapper() {
        public double f(double x, double y) {
            return 10 * Math.sin(x / 10) * Math.cos(y / 20) * x;
        }
    };

    // Define range and precision for the function to plot
    Range range = new Range(-150, 150);
    int steps = 50;

    // Create the object to represent the function over the given range.
    org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Shape surface = (Shape) Builder.buildOrthonormal(new OrthonormalGrid(range, steps, range, steps), mapper);
    surface.setColorMapper(new ColorMapper(new ColorMapRainbow(), surface.getBounds().getZmin(), surface.getBounds().getZmax(), new Color(1, 1, 1, .5f)));
    surface.setWireframeDisplayed(true);
    surface.setWireframeColor(Color.BLACK);
    //surface.setFace(new ColorbarFace(surface));
    surface.setFaceDisplayed(true);
    //surface.setFace2dDisplayed(true); // opens a colorbar on the right part of the    
 display

    // Create a chart
    Chart chart = new Chart();
    chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surface);
    return chart;
}
}
```

problem is a error about import javax.swing.JFrame; "The import javax.swing cannot be resolved" i can't understand whats reson of this error. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> problem is a error about import javax.swing.JFrame;

This problem is due Jdk configuration with Eclipse.

Comment: and do you know how can i fix that?